# OpenLayers styling lines between points

Tags: openlayers-2, style, features

I drew a line between two points and would like to change the line styles but currently is not working as expected. Tried to add the style into the features. Am i missing something?

```
        var points = [ 
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( lng, lat ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( qlng, qlat  ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo)
        ];

        var styles = { 
          strokeColor: '#000000', 
          strokeOpacity: 2,
          strokeWidth: 10
        };

        feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points, null, styles)
        );

        vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style is a parameter of the feature, not the linestring

```
    feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points),
            null,
            styles
    );
```

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation and solution.